# ThreeJS image texture on merged objects

Tags: three.js, render, texture-mapping

Help! I'm trying to create and merge two different objects in THREEjs.  I have one image and I need it to be stretched over the entire merged object once.  Currently it is doing it twice, once on the top and once on the bottom, like they are still two separate objects.

```
var texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load('//s1.postimg.org/26dva6d58v/peace.png');
texture.alphaTest = 0.9;
texture.needsUpdate = true;

color = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial( {
  side: THREE.DoubleSide,
  color: 0x949494,
  map: texture
} );
var size = {'top': 1.395, 'bottom': 1.11, 'height': 3.5};       

cylinderGeo1 = new THREE.CylinderGeometry( size.top, size.bottom, size.height, 50, null, true );
cylinderGeo1.applyMatrix( new THREE.Matrix4().makeTranslation(0, size.height/2, 0) );
cylinder1 = new THREE.Mesh(cylinderGeo1);

cylinderGeo2 = new THREE.CylinderGeometry( size.top * 2,size.top, size.height, 50, null, true );
cylinderGeo2.applyMatrix( new THREE.Matrix4().makeTranslation(0, (size.height/2) + size.height, 0) );
cylinder2 = new THREE.Mesh(cylinderGeo2);

cupGeo = new THREE.Geometry();;

cylinder1.updateMatrix();
cupGeo.merge(cylinderGeo1, cylinder1.matrix);
cylinder2.updateMatrix();
cupGeo.merge(cylinderGeo2, cylinder2.matrix);

cup = new THREE.Mesh(cupGeo, color);
cup.updateMatrix();
scene.add(cup);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dj2k6y8t/16/

[edit] You may need to zoom on the canvas to get it render.

Comment: It is because of the UV coordinates on the objects.

Comment: @2pha - I'm very new to this and it's only for 1 project at work.  I don't understand all of the 3d terminology, like vertices, faces, meshes, UV, etc..  Can you please alter my fiddle and show me?

Comment: It is to do with the model, not the code. And no, I will not do your work for you.